# Integral asked on MIT bee qualifier 2012 $\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying to solve this one but I have no clue, I put it into wolfram and the result is absurd, considering this one is taken from MIT bee qualifier 2012, this is the integral:
$$\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} \, dx$$

Comment: Why such a negative reaction to this question ?

Comment: What have you attempted? Include it in the post so it doesn't get closed

Comment: @Dylan Why is it necessary to include attempts to avoid closure ?

Comment: I agree with Rene, I think given that this is a contest math question a downvote and a close vote due to not showing an attempt is less appropriate than a homework question. Nevertheless it is more helpful to note that $I = 2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x + \frac{1}{x} + 1}$ rather than the Wolfram Alpha output.

Comment: I don't know, I'm just following from past questions that have been closed due to lack of attempt. Personally I don't even mind homework questions.

Comment: @Dylan So why enforce something you dont agree with ?

Comment: Because I want to help OPs avoid having the questions closed, like what's happened to me in the past. I have no control over how the rules are created. Can't beat them, join them.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{x-1}{x+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}
&=\int\frac{x^{-1/2}-x^{-3/2}}{x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}\right)^2-1}}\\
&=2\int\frac1{x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\!\left(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}\right)^2-1}}\\
&=2\int\frac1u\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\\[9pt]
&=2\sec^{-1}(u)+C\\[15pt]
&=2\sec^{-1}\left(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the integrand as

$$ \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^2\left(x + \dfrac{1}{x} + 1\right)}} =  \frac{x^2 - 1}{(x^3 + 2x^2 + x)\sqrt{x + \dfrac{1}{x} + 1}} \\
= \frac{1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2}}{\left( x + \dfrac{1}{x} + 2 \right)\sqrt{x + \dfrac{1}{x} + 1}} $$

Then make the substitution $u^2 = x + \dfrac{1}{x} + 1$ to get

$$ \int \frac{2}{u^2+1} du = 2\arctan u + C $$

Comment: Yes but we also have $2u \ du = \left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx$

Comment: My mistake, just tired, this is entirely correct. thx!